# how to loopback a subdomain with same ip in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, adapter, loopback

Ok i'm trying to loopback a subdomain of some webserver. There's 3 subdomains in the website. www, static and play. I pinged the static.website.com and i got this ip 123.123.3 (Example only). So i tried to loopback the static subdomain in my localhost by configuring the ipv4 of the loopback adapter:

```
IP Address : 123.123.3
Subnet Mask : 255.255.0.0
```

When i visited the play.website.com , i was shocked that it also shows my localhost webserver. Is there any way to spoof that subdomain that will also shows the same ip as the webserver?

**PS:** I don't want to configure the host file from *c:/windows/system32/drivers/* for some reasons.

Comment: Hard to imagine your system setup. Too little information. Anyways, you've got full control over a domain ex b.a and can point this and all it's sub domains ex c.b.a, d.c.b.a to whatever ip address you like, individually and even with a resolution of certain services. This is done where the domain is hosted. Are you the hosting party or is this somewhere else?

Comment: Hey, i don't own the webserver, i am planning for local proxying

Comment: Put up a dns server and study how they work. Anyways, as I said, you provide too little information.